# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' и регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, opencart

Как мне выделить часть адреса по регулярному выражению, пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы во всех страницах, где присутствует в адресе catalog вывести код. Может я усложняю и можно сделать иначе?))

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '(^\/(catalog)\/(.+)$)') {
echo "blah-blah-blah";
}
```

P.S. Движок Opencart - нужно для определенных товаров и для некоторых категорий (2 из 6) вывести некий код в карточке товара.

Comment: Что делает конструкция isset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сделать так:

```
if (preg_match("/catalog/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    // Вывести blah-blah-blah
} else {
    // ничего не выводить
}
```

[FYI](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Красава! Все работает! А почему i после catalog/ ?
и как мне если Я выведу в какой-либо категории код, например в /category1/ но на некоторых товарах этой категории не нужно. Как сделать?

Comment: Автор, Вам нужно почитать документацию по регулярным выражениям. Ответ на Ваш второй вопрос - http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Я очень рекомендую сначала попробовать разобраться самому, а уже после задавать конкретные вопросы.

Comment: с буквой i разобрался. А вот как сделать исключение не понял